# How to use authentication with Nexus hosted Bower without plain text credentials

Tags: bower, nexus, nexus3, private-bower

We have Bower hosted in a Nexus 3 repository. Our `.bowerrc` file looks like:

```
{
    "directory": "bower_components",
    "registry": {
        "search": [
            "https://<host>/nexus/repository/bower/"
        ]
    },
    "resolvers": [ "bower-nexus3-resolver" ]
}
```

So far it has had anonymous access so this worked fine. However, Nexus has now had authentication enabled so we need some way of authenticating.

I've read [some documentation](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/bower-repositories) and it suggests we need to add

```
{
  "nexus" : {
    "username" : "myusername",
    "password" : "mypassword"
  }
}
```

But this uses plain text credentials. Is there a way to use authentication without plain text credentials?

Answer (score 0):

Professional (licensed) customers can use user tokens as documented [here](https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM3/Security+Setup+with+User+Tokens).

To OSS users, I know that might sound a bit like NXRM doesn't care, but what is shown there comes from Bower not from NXRM, so to have that guarded, is really (in this example) a Bower change.